# Moving Functions in Header File to get a clean sort

Tags: c++, coding-style, semantics

I'm working on a large project and some of the headers are grown over the time. I would like to put the functions in the header file into the right order to keep the semantics clean.

I could copy and paste them, but I would more like drag them up and down in a different view (without the comments). May be you know a tool to order such kind of stuff easy.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for all your sorting needs is `sort`.

Your declarations will typically look like

```
type1 SomeName::fun();
type2 funtastic();
```

With `sort` you can select the column used for comparing. If you want to sort using the function name or class, in above example that would be column 2.

```
$ sort -k2 header.h > sorted_header.h
```

Maybe your editor has the option to run an external command on some selected lines. That would make things even more integrated.

Comment: +1 -  I never thought of using `sort` in this manner.  Props for the tip.

Comment: @plucked: I am not sure I understand what you mean by *semantic*. Maybe you could update your question with an explanation of what exactly you expect.